# Is the story plotline or arc for the Star Wars series going to be overhauled with Carrie Fisher's death?

Tags: star-wars

I think it's pretty safe to assume that Carrie Fisher had a pretty major role planned for her in the remaining two movies.

Is there any **official word** on how her death impacts the upcoming movies?  I read that they already had their footage for the next one shot, but if it was shot with plans for her being in the last one, they will need to change something.

Will they write her out with a tragic death using current footage, or CGI her like they did for the Tarkin/originally-Peter-Cushing character?  Or some combination?

[Carrie Fisher finished shooting Star Wars:Episode VIII before her death](http://variety.com/2016/film/news/carrie-fisher-dead-death-star-wars-viii-8-1201948826/)

Comment: I suspect this is too speculative for an answer.

Comment: @Paulie_D -I'm asking for actual verifiable information about how the movie producers are dealing with this.  I'm not asking for any speculation.  I'm not sure why you'd think that a movie already shot and a plotline for another already in the works, and a death that already happened would require speculation about how they all come together.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are correct that *Episode VIII, The Last Jedi* had wrapped up filming prior to Fisher's death.

The offical Star Wars site released [the following blurb](http://www.starwars.com/news/star-wars-episode-viii-wraps-shooting) on July 22, 2016:

> Director Rian Johnson announced today on the official Star Wars Facebook and Twitter channels that Star Wars: Episode VIII has wrapped shooting. “Final slate of the final shot,” Johnson wrote of an accompanying short video. **“VIII is officially wrapped.** Thanks to the best cast and crew in the galaxy, and thanks to the fans for all the love and support through the whole process. Cannot wait to put it together and share it with you all!”

They [also confirmed](http://www.starwars.com/news/a-statement-regarding-new-rumors) on January 13, 2017 that they have no plans to use CGI to recreate Fisher as General Organa:

> We don’t normally respond to fan or press speculation, but there is a rumor circulating that we would like to address. **We want to assure our fans that Lucasfilm has no plans to digitally recreate Carrie Fisher’s performance as Princess or General Leia Organa.**
>
> Carrie Fisher was, is, and always will be a part of the Lucasfilm family. She was our princess, our general, and more importantly, our friend. We are still hurting from her loss. We cherish her memory and legacy as Princess Leia, and will always strive to honor everything she gave to Star Wars.

<s>So we know she (meaning Fisher) will not appear in Episode IX, but we do not know at this time how they will handle this. Even though her passing was tragic to many in the community, I doubt they will give away huge plot spoilers because of it. Star Wars been known for its dramatic reveals in the OT (Vader) and now the ST (Han). It is possible that role will be recast and General Organa will remain in the story in the same way that Michael Gambon replaced Richard Harris as Dumbledore in the *Harry Potter* films.</s>

J.J. Abrams has [released a statement](https://www.starwars.com/news/star-wars-episode-ix-cast-announced) along with the rest of casting of Episode IX concerning Fisher/Leia.

> The role of Leia Organa will once again be played by Carrie Fisher, **using previously unreleased footage** shot for Star Wars: The Force Awakens. “We desperately loved Carrie Fisher,” says Abrams. “Finding a truly satisfying conclusion to the Skywalker saga without her eluded us. **We were never going to recast, or use a CG character.** With the support and blessing from her daughter, Billie, we have found a way to honor Carrie’s legacy and role as Leia in Episode IX by using unseen footage we shot together in Episode VII.”

Comment: What do OT and ST stand for in this answer?

Comment: Original Trilogy and Sequel Trilogy I'm guessing.

Comment: Their comment does not preclude using already shot footage.

Comment: @zeta-band Or even using a different actor.  (Although I'm not sure fans would let them try that.)

Comment: @Bob Do the fans really get any control over that?

Comment: @Catija - through social media blowback, PR nightmares and box office "voting," sure.

Answer (score 3):

As the previous answer well states, it appears to be inconsequential to ***The Last Jedi***.

However, it will greatly impact **Episode IX**

> W**hat’s perhaps all the more maddening is the reveal that Episode IX
>   would have put Fisher’s Leia front and center**, in the same way that
>   Harrison Ford‘s Han Solo was at the crux of The Force Awakens, and
>   Mark Hamill‘s Luke is at the heart of The Last Jedi. Kathleen Kennedy
>   confirms, “The minute she finished, she grabbed me and said, ‘I’d
>   better be at the forefront of IX!’ […] She thought IX would be her
>   movie. And it would have been.”
>   http://collider.com/star-wars-episode-9-carrie-fisher-role/#rian-johnso
>
> > As the world still grapples with the fact that Carrie Fisher is gone,
> >     the galaxy far, far away is coming to terms with the loss of its own
> >     princess general.
> >
> > Lucasfilm president Kathleen Kennedy tells EW the story team and
> >     filmmakers have come up with a plan for how to handle Fisher’s absence
> >     in 2019’s planned Star Wars: Episode IX.
> >
> > The actress won’t be recreated digitally, but unfortunately, **that also
> >     means Leia Organa won’t be a part of the story**.
> >
> > “Obviously, with Carrie having passed away, it shook everybody,”
> >     Kennedy says. **As they tried to figure out what this meant for Leia’s
> >     continuing story, the only option was to leave their original ideas
> >     behind. “We pretty much started over,**” Kennedy adds.
> >     http://ew.com/movies/2017/04/14/kathleen-kennedy-episode-ix-carrie-fisher-death/

In addition it should be noted that Collin Trevorrow is no longer
 directing/writing episode IX. Some reports suggest that he was slow on
 drafts, but given Carrie Fisher's death, one might speculate the
 rewrights were too taxing being a relatively newer film-maker. JJ
 Abrams has now taken back the reins on both counts. Also early on it
 was stated that Carrie Fisher would not be CGI-ed into the films, but
 this was also when they stated would put things on pause for a while
 (as far as the public is concerned)--recently [Billie Lourd](http://www.etonline.com/news/221131_carrie_fisher_daughter_billie_lourd_named_beneficiary_of_estate_as_final_assets_are_revealed) did become
 the benificary of Carrie Fisher's estate and there might be room to
 argue that Disney/Lucasfilm was waiting for that and that Carrie's
 presense in the film could change **in some way**, considering the 
 following tadbit from Trevorrow before he was fired:

> "She was a major character, that's not a secret," Trevorrow, who
>   didn't get the chance to meet Fisher before her death, said in a
>   recent interview with *Cinemablend* while promoting his upcoming
>   film The Book of Henry. "It was extremely sad for all of us, mostly
>   just because she was so loved by the Star Wars family and everyone
>   that worked with her. **I feel like our options are limited mostly by
>   ourselves, in that there [are] only certain things that we are willing
>   to do. But I can guarantee it will be handled with love and respect,
>   and all the soul that Carrie Fisher deserves**."
>
> Lucasfilm head Kathleen Kennedy revealed in a recent interview
>   with Vanity Fair that the company has no plans to recreate Leia
>   digitally for the film, **and will instead find a way to honor the
>   character without Fisher present**. Still, she said, Fisher's loss was
>   deeply felt. "Because Harrison [Ford] was front and center on VII, and
>   Mark is front and center on VIII, [Fisher] thought IX would be her
>   movie," Kennedy said. "And it would have been."
>
> Read More:
>   http://www.looper.com/68990/trevorrow-star-wars-9-carrie-fisher/?utm_campaign=clip

---

**UPDATE:** The Force Awakens [unused footage](https://deadline.com/2018/07/star-wars-digital-appearance-by-late-carrie-fisher-gets-brothers-backing-1202435687/) will now be used in Episode IX and Carrie Fisher (Leia) will be included in the film:

> “As we, her family, as well as her extended family of fans around the
>   world so believe, Carrie’s ‘Princess Leia is forever entrenched in the
>   franchise and her indelible presence is fundamental to the film,” Todd
>   Fisher said.  “J.J. Abrams understood Carrie’s iconic role,  and he
>   has masterfully re-crafted this final entry to include this unused 
>   and very last footage of Carrie ever taken, without resorting to CGI
>   or animatronics. Our family and her fans will look forward with great
>   anticipation for this one! Her force will forever be with us!”

[Cast Press Release](https://www.starwars.com/news/star-wars-episode-ix-cast-announced) for Episode IX also includes Carrie Fisher's name:

> Star Wars: Episode IX will begin filming at London’s Pinewood Studios
>   on August 1, 2018. J.J. Abrams returns to direct the final installment
>   of the Skywalker saga. Abrams co-wrote the screenplay with Chris
>   Terrio.
>
> Returning cast members include Daisy Ridley, Adam Driver, John Boyega,
>   Oscar Isaac, Lupita Nyong’o, Domhnall Gleeson, Kelly Marie Tran,
>   Joonas Suotamo, and Billie Lourd. Joining the cast of Episode IX are
>   Naomi Ackie, Richard E. Grant, and Keri Russell, who will be joined by
>   veteran Star Wars actors Mark Hamill, Anthony Daniels, and Billy Dee
>   Williams, who will reprise his role as Lando Calrissian.
>
> **The role of Leia Organa will once again be played by Carrie Fisher,
>   using previously unreleased footage shot for Star Wars: The Force
>   Awakens. “We desperately loved Carrie Fisher,” says Abrams. “Finding a
>   truly satisfying conclusion to the Skywalker saga without her eluded
>   us. We were never going to recast, or use a CG character. With the
>   support and blessing from her daughter, Billie, we have found a way to
>   honor Carrie’s legacy and role as Leia in Episode IX by using unseen
>   footage we shot together in Episode VII.”**
>
> Composer John Williams, who has scored every chapter in the Star Wars
>   saga since 1977’s A New Hope, will return to a galaxy far, far away
>   with Episode IX.
>
> Star Wars: Episode IX will be produced by Kathleen Kennedy, J.J.
>   Abrams, and Michelle Rejwan, and executive produced by Callum Greene
>   and Jason McGatlin. The crew includes Dan Mindel (Director of
>   Photography), Rick Carter and Kevin Jenkins (Co-Production Designers),
>   Michael Kaplan (Costume Designer), Neal Scanlan (Creature and Droid
>   FX), Maryann Brandon and Stefan Grube (Editors), Roger Guyett (VFX
>   Supervisor), Tommy Gormley (1st AD), and Victoria Mahoney (2nd Unit
>   Director).
>
> Release is scheduled for December 2019.